# Stone-effect porcelain stoneware: problems with stone veins

Tags: materials, procedural

I'm having some difficulties reproducing the veins effect in the stone. I can't find a way to make them run along a direction and randomly split here and there.

I am using a Voronoi texture but the lines tend to wrap around themselves (creating rings and semi-circles) or they overlap too much. For the test render, I had to fine-tune the scale of the textures in order to achieve a somewhat acceptable result, and it's still very far from the desired effect.

**Desired effect** (at the end of the linked page, under "Variations", you can find different examples): https://www.leaceramiche.com/collection/nextone

[image: Desired effect]

**My attempt** (too few veins and they are not splitting like in the desired effect, if I try to increase their number they wrap around and overlap with each other. Ignore the difference in colour, for the moment):
[image: My attempt]

**Nodes** (a lot of trial and error here):
[image: Nodes]

Comment: You can't really do branching paths in the shader nodes.  See [this comment](https://blenderartists.org/t/procedural-cracks-and-creases/672749/5?u=martyfouts) on BA for more information on workarounds.

Comment: Thank you, knowing the technical name of what I'm trying to achieve helps a lot as I can make a more targeted research. Do you think there is a way to achieve a similar effect in a less complex way? Maybe some vector math to "filter" the veins to be shown mostly in a specific direction. I'm out of ideas. It feels like it should be easy to procedurally generated stone veins in a 3D rendering software.

Comment: The best I've ever been able to do is have two copies of the cracks, offset one slightly in some way, and then mask the offset one with another texture to hide most of its cracks.  It helps to create the cracks and then scale along one dimension so that they stretch in that direction as well.